# Filter a value in all properties with Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, eloquent, laravel-livewire

This question is very similar to [Laravel filter a value in all columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28543166/laravel-filter-a-value-in-all-columns). Sorry, if it turns out as a duplicate later on, but I have another working code to provide.

What does work is filtering on the client side via JavaScript:

```
    filterfunction : function(entry, filter)
    {
        if(filter != null)
            filter.trim().split(' ').forEach(function(item){
                if(!this.eachRecursive(entry, item))
                    return false;
            });                    
        return true;
    },
    eachRecursive: function(obj, localfilter) {
        for(const key in obj) {
            if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
                continue;
            if(typeof obj[key] == "object" && obj[key] !== null){
                if(this.eachRecursive(obj[key], localfilter))
                    return true;
            }
            else
            if((obj[key] + "").toLowerCase().indexOf(localfilter.toLowerCase()) != -1)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    },
```

The filter function is used as the filter function for the Bootstrap-Vue table component like described in custom-filter-function.

The question is now: how to achieve similar functionality in the Laravel-Backend (for using with [Livewire](https://laravel-livewire.com/))?

I can imagine, that listing all columns via getColumnListing, mentioned in [Laravel filter a value in all columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28543166/laravel-filter-a-value-in-all-columns) is possible, but this wouldn't suffice, I still need the relations, like in [laravel mysql query with multiple where orwhere and inner join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27063077/laravel-mysql-query-with-multiple-where-orwhere-and-inner-join).
Currently, I'm trying out to convert the Eloquent object to JSON and then to parse it, as it includes all the loaded relations [eloquent-serialization](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#relationships). But this seems like the last resort and a kind of misuse of serialization.

Comment: Great work on the research. Because you also want to filter related records the problem gets exceedingly complex. You could write elaborate database queries, or let PHP/Laravel do all the filtering for you. It's even possible to add ElasticSearch to the stack. It depends on what you are trying achieve.

Comment: I thought about using Laravel Scout for full-text search. But the main feature of this is: sorting by relevance. I don't need this per se. But I neither don't have any experience about the Scout component so I can't say if the overhead is justified for my use case.

Comment: It looks decent. Keep in mind that it will probably create a separate store for the data (same as ElasticSearch), that means that stuff can get out of sync (your search-index may return results that are outdated or have been removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I'm going to use the route over converting to json. However, I found a way to not to parse json by regular expressions. Instead, I convert the jsonified collection back to php objects. With them I'm able to reimplement the functions from above:

```
private function eachRecursive(stdClass $obj, string $localfilter) {
    foreach($obj as $key => $val){
        if(is_object($val)){
            if($this->eachRecursive($val, $localfilter))
                return true;
        } elseif(is_array($val)){
            foreach($val as $k => $v)
                if($this->eachRecursive($v, $localfilter))
                    return true;
        } elseif(stripos(strval($val), $localfilter) !== false){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private function filterfunction(Collection $collection, string $filter){
    $retVal = [];

    foreach (json_decode($collection->toJson()) as $entity){
        foreach(explode(' ', trim($filter)) as $localfilter)
            if(!$this->eachRecursive($entity, $localfilter))
                continue 2;
        array_push($retVal, $entity->id);
    }

    return $retVal;
}
```