# Eloquent ORM LeftJoin with ifnull and orOn using is not working

Tags: php, eloquent, left-join, laravel-8

I want to write this sql query with eloquent orm laravel 8.

```
Select * from apples as a

Left Join Brands as b 

On ( (IFNULL(a.x, '') || IFNULL(a.y, '') || IFNULL(a.z, '')) =
                    (IFNULL(b.t, '') || IFNULL(b.e, '') || IFNULL(b.f, '')))
```

My eloquent query:

```
  Apple::select('*')
   ->leftJoin('Brands', function ($join) {
                $join->on('Brands.t', '=', 'Apples.x');

                $join->on(function ($join2) {
                    $join2
                        ->orOn('Brands .t', '=', 'Apples.x')
                        ->whereRaw("REPLACE('Brands .t',' ','')!=?", '')
                        ->whereRaw("REPLACE('Apples.x',' ','')!=?", '')
                        ->where("Apples.x","!=",null)
                        ->where("Brands .t","!=",null);
                    $join2
                        ->orOn('Brands .e', '=', 'Apples.y')
                        ->whereRaw("REPLACE('Brands .e',' ','')!=?", '')
                        ->whereRaw("REPLACE('Apples.y',' ','')!=?", '')
                        ->where("Apples.y","!=",null)
                        ->where("Brands .e","!=",null);
                });

            })
```

Apple Columns

x -> Alphanumeric

y-> Alphanumeric

z-> Alphanumeric

Brand Columns

t-> Alphanumeric

e-> Alphanumeric

f-> Alphanumeric

All columns values can be null or empty string like this ->  "    " without.

Every time matching columns Apple x and Brand t.

For example db show. Any columns contain be whitespace values or null or empty string.

#### Apple

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 2 |  |
| ABC |  | 4 |
| ABC |  |  |
| ABC | 5 | 6 |

#### Brand

| t | e | f | g |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 2 | null | ABC_NL |
| ABC | '' | 4 | ABC_TR |
| ABC | null | whitespace_string | ABC_USA |
| ABC | 5 | 6 | ABC_GER |

How can do access true g result with laravel eloquent orm query ?

Comment: Try using orWhere instead of where , check the below solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27063077/laravel-mysql-query-with-multiple-where-orwhere-and-inner-join

Comment: Thank you for answer, but i need to complete code pieces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.

```
->leftJoin('Apple', function ($join) {
                $join->on(
                    DB::raw("IFNULL(Apple.x, '') || IFNULL(Apple.y, '') || IFNULL(Apple.z, '')"),
                    DB::raw("IFNULL(Brand.t, '') || IFNULL(Brand.e, '') || IFNULL(Brand.f, '')")
                );
            })
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).